# What is the image that shows to the left of the serp in Edge?

Tags: seo, search-results

I am having the same issue in EDGE. A square image shows the word press logo, not my logo. I checked my site identifier, and my logo is within the wordpress admin, and so is my favicon, but there is no option for this.

[image: Site-Identifier-Block-left-of-Serp]

Comment: Edge is a browser, not a search engine.  Is this for Bing search results?

Comment: When did your site go live ?

Comment: This is certainly the "Bing" search results, not "Edge". This is likely to be a caching issue, "favicons" are often cached persistently. If your site was "live" during development and the real favicon was only added recently then that could explain what you are seeing. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: I realized after I inspected the element that is was Bing, thank you for clarifying.  Also the favicon has been on my site for some time, my site has been up since 2017.

Comment: Thank you for your help, hopefully they will update this element, since i have no control.

Comment: Now that I know where it originates I can try to fix it, I found this: The website must have a valid sitemap.xml file, and the sitemap should include the URL of the favicon file. Once these requirements are met, Bing will automatically detect the favicon and display it in the search results next to the website's title and description.

Comment: @DebbieTeter "I found this: ... and the sitemap should include the URL of the favicon file." - Huh, what a strange requirement!? Where did you find this? I can only find [a post from the Microsoft community forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/all/what-are-the-requirements-to-display-favicon-on/236d6598-41e2-483c-9950-aae8714d943c)?

Comment: @DebbieTeter I'm not convinced _that_ is a requirement? You currently have a "favicon" (albeit the wrong one) displayed in the Bing search results (most don't) - but you don't have any such entry in your sitemap. (?) If it was a "requirement" then you would presumably need an entry in the sitemap to display the "wrong" favicon?!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 things that need to be fixed:

1. Your **favicon.ico** actually redirects to a **PNG** file, named *cropped-Garmat-G-32x32.png* - This is not a good practice. You should either have a proper ***.ico*** file, **or**, tell the search engines explicitly that your icon is a ***PNG***.
2. You should declare your icon as a meta tag. The proper syntax is:

`<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/favicon.ico">`

In your particular case, the tag could read:

`<link rel="icon" href="/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/cropped-Garmat-G-32x32.png">`

Comment: The OP has already set the appropriate `link` element in the HTML `head` section, albeit a long way down the source (line #417) - which could itself be an issue?